# XAMP stop php execution without server restart

Tags: php, xampp

Im using xamp for local php server. Is it possible to end execution of some really long script without restarting xamp php service?

Comment: How are you running the script? If you're running it in your browser you should be able to just hit stop.

Comment: If you are running the script in CLI mode `from command line` a `ctrl+c` should kill it.

Comment: I guess you mean XAMPP not XAMP

Comment: @RiggsFolly `ctrl + c` doesnt seem to work for me, in fact nothing does it continues executing and i have to manually close and reopen the CLI

Comment: Are you runnig on windows or a *nix

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Apache only might be quicker

Answer (score 0):

To set maximum execution time of a specific PHP page, use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in your PHP page.

To set maximum execution time of all PHP pages at once, use [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in php.ini file.